# Scrollable table, freezed first column with CSS, Joomla

Tags: html, css, joomla, html-table, css-position

I know that there some extensions that can make this happen but I want to do it this way (if possible). I have tried several methods with "child" and nowrap command but can't get it to work. I have made table and everything is fine. However I want it to be more advanced on mobile devices and to lock the first column on place -> everything else should scroll left. How it could be done with only HTML and CSS. I have theme.css with CSS code, and will make Custom HTML code module for the page with table itself.

Also here are some solutions, but by using suggested methods my table is breaking and not showing correctly.

```css
.table-container{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 900px){
    .table-container {
       overflow: visible;
    }
}

.table-container body{
    padding: 1em;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #222;
}
.table-container table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0px solid #620376;
}
.table-container th, td{
    padding: 0.25em 0.75em;
    text-align: left;
}
.table-container th{
    background-color: #000000;
    white-space: nowrap;
   color: white;
}
.table-container td{
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #929292;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-container">
   <table class="data-table">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th> </th>
            <th> </th>
            <th><center>Parameter S</center></th>
            <th><center>Parameter S</center></th>
            <th><center>Parameter S</center></th>
            <th><center>Parameter S</center></th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>Parameter 1</td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
                <td><center>m2</center></td>
                <td><center>m2</center></td>
         </tr>   
         <tr>
            <td>Parameter 2</td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
                <td><center>m2</center></td>
                <td><center>m2</center></td>
         </tr>   
            <tr>
            <td>Parameter 3</td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
                <td><center>m2</center></td>
                <td><center>m2</center></td>
         </tr>   
            <tr>
            <td>Parameter 3</td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
                <td><center>m2</center></td>
                <td><center>m2</center></td>
         </tr>   
            <tr>
            <td>Parameter 4</td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
                <td><center>m2</center></td>
                <td><center>m2</center></td>
         </tr>   
                        <tr>
            <td>Parameter 5</td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
                <td><center>m2</center></td>
                <td><center>m2</center></td>
         </tr>
                        <tr>
            <td>Parameter 6</td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
                <td><center>m2</center></td>
                <td><center>m2</center></td>
         </tr>
                        <tr>
            <td>Parameter 7</td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
                <td><center>m2</center></td>
                <td><center>m2</center></td>
         </tr>
                        <tr>
            <td>Parameter 8</td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
                <td><center>m2</center></td>
                <td><center>m2</center></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

Comment: out of interest, have you tried giving the first column of td's a class and setting them as fixed(or other) in css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably just suggest two serpate tables.

In your first table you just set it to never move like you want.

The second table you make scrollable.

```
<table class="New Table for header only">
<th colspan="# of columns">Table</th>
<td>Ranger Rover</td>
<td>Mercedes</td>
<td>toyota</td>
</table>
```

Then just incorporate your data from the other table without the headers attached.

This should work right? Unless I misunderstand the question.